Proving the number of edges by Induction
Let there be a simple graph denoted $B_{n}$. There are $2^n$ vertices in $B_{n}$, and each vertex is labelled with a binary string of length $n$. Two vertices are adjacent if the bitwise-or (inclusive or) of their two binary labels is the binary string of length n that is all 1s. I have to prove that the number of edges in $B_{n} = \frac{{3^n - 1}}{2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
I am trying to prove this by Induction. If it is valid for $k$ then it must also be valid for $k+1$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ but I am not sure what am I supposed to add to this equation to account for the extra vertex in the Induction Step.

Do you mean to say that there are $2^n$ vertices in $B_n$, and that each possible length-$n$ binary string is the label of some vertex?

@Arthur, yes it is $2^n$, my apologies for the typo.

Are you assuming that each vertex is labelled with a different binary string?

Hint: If you draw the graph at subsequent levels, you would see that, given the edges at level $n$, there is structure to the edges that need to be drawn at level $n+1$.  In particular, the goal would be to figure out $E_{n+1} = E_n + \dots$, where $E_n$ is the number of edges at level $n$.  If you figure that out, the proof should then be easy.
